# Safaricom api request failed for accesstoken

Tags: php

I'm currently facing a critical issue with my PHP code responsible for obtaining an access token (access_token.php). The core problem revolves around the fact that I'm unable to successfully retrieve the access token, and I'm reaching out to seek help and guidance in resolving this pressing matter.

The specific error message that has been plaguing my efforts is as follows: "cURL Error: Failed to connect to 196.201.214.202: Network is unreachable." This error has been a persistent roadblock in my development process, indicating that my code is struggling to establish a network connection with the host situated at the IP address 196.201.214.202.

This issue has prompted a thorough investigation into multiple potential causes:

1. Network Connectivity: I have ensured the presence of a stable and functional internet connection within my server or local development environment, substantiating that external resources can be successfully accessed.
2. Firewall and Network Configuration: I've meticulously reviewed firewall and network configuration settings to rule out any interference with the outbound connections necessary for my code.
3. Access Token URL: A comprehensive review of the access token URL has been conducted, ensuring its correctness and accessibility. Any updates or alterations to the API endpoint have been rigorously assessed.
4. cURL Configuration: A critical assessment of my cURL configuration has been carried out to guarantee its alignment with the required headers and authentication credentials, which include the consumer key and secret.

Despite my dedicated efforts, the issue remains unresolved, leaving me in a state of urgency, seeking assistance from anyone who can extend their expertise and insights. Your invaluable support will undoubtedly play a pivotal role in overcoming this roadblock, ultimately enabling me to procure the essential access token for the seamless operation of my application. Your contribution to this endeavor would be immensely appreciated. Thank you for your assistance in advance.